# Installation Profile with Restrict by IP module

Tags: 8, configuration, installation-profiles

I have an installation profile I use for automating the setup of Drupal 8 websites.

Almost everything works perfectly, including configuration items such as date formats and file system, and default content type fields.

However, the [Restrict by IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip) module configuration does not work. If I use the configuration import GUI in Drupal and paste in the contents of the file, it works as expected, so I'm confident that the syntax is correct.

The only thing I can think of is that the configuration references the administrator user account and its ID (1), and maybe at the time the profile is processed that account is not yet ready.

Is there a reason why the configuration isn't applied during installation?

Comment: Not sure but I think user 1 with superpowers is still always created. This will change in D9 soon I think, but I can't find the change record right now. And: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @leymannx I've updated the post to add a question.